# TFLearn "cannot feed value of shape."

Tags: python, tensorflow

I started using a very basic Deep Belief Network in Node.js but it wasn't fast enough. Essentially it was using a `X` and `Y` where each is an array of arrays; `X` is the data to train and `Y` is the result.

So I would feed it something like `var x=[[1,2,3], [1,3,2]]` *etc. etc.* and `y=[[1,0], [1,0]]`. Then I would give some data such as `[2,3,1]` and it would predict the `y`.

I'm lost on how to do this in tfslearn. I can learn on my own but I've hit a point where I'm not sure what to even Google.

I can get the examples working if it's just a single array.

Every time I try using an array of arrays I get:

> cannot feed value of shape

Comment: Can you show the code that gave you the error? In general terms TFlearn/tensorflow should work as you describe, you first fit the model and then predict on a given data. You can also take a look at the [tflearn tutorial](http://tflearn.org/tutorials/quickstart.html)

Comment: that link helped a lot. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the input shape incorrectly for my data set. This helped a lot: http://tflearn.org/tutorials/quickstart.html

```
# Data loading and preprocessing
# Building deep neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 4])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 32)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Training
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_metric=True)
```